# Line of overflowing text with ellipsis and a div on the end

Tags: html, css, ellipsis

I have a long line of dynamic text followed by a button image. When the width is such that the content overflows, I would like the text to be trimmed with an ellipsis, yet keep the button visible.

So from this:

This is my long text blah blah [button]

To this:

This is my long... [button]

I can't get the button to stick to the end of the text. If the div with the text is set to display:inline-block then the ellipsis no longer appears. The text changes so I can't use fixed widths.

Here's the basic structure:

```
<div>
    <div id="text">A long line of text that overflows when window is narrow</div>
    <div id="button"></div>    
</div>
```

with some css:

```
#text {
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:block;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-right:50px;

}
#button{
    background-color:lightblue;
    height:20px;
    width:30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

with a corresponding [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vK8fE/) for tweaking purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I've made it work finally - using a flex box... here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vK8fE/8/)

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="text">A long line of text that overflows when window is narrow</div>
        <div id="button"></div>    
</div>

#container{
    display:flex;
}
#text {
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#button{
    background-color:lightblue;
    height:20px;
    min-width:30px;
    width:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that may work for you.

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/vK8fE/4/)**

You make use of the containing div to make the others `display: inline-block` and then give the text div a % width so the overflow can happen. You can make the % larger or smaller, but I found 80% worked nicely. It will still wrap when you size the window very narrow since the button has a fixed width.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="text"><span>A long line of text that overflows when window is narrow</span></div>
    <div id="button"></div>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{    
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-right:50px; 
}

.container > div {display: inline-block;}

#text {
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80%;
}

#button{
    background-color:lightblue;
    height:20px;
    width:30px;
}
```

Comment: It's close but it overflows before the edge of the container has reached the button. I've played with the padding and width percentage but can't make it work as I'd like it to.

Comment: Also when the window is wide, there's a big gap between the button and the text.

Comment: I said as much in my answer, the button will wrap if the page is sized down too small. and since the text has a % the space will continue to grow. I don't think there is a pure CSS solve for this if you want it to keep the same HTML structure.

Comment: The structure doesn't matter, it's only the behaviour i care about. Starting to suspect it might not be possible though.